# Grouped sum by distinct values in array

Tags: sorting, multidimensional-array, julia

I am a newbie to Julia ( and to all programming tbh). I have an array that looks like

5048574×2 Array{Float64,2}:
22   1990
3    1990
4    1991
3    1992
4    1992

I need to sum the values in column 1 that correspond to the years in column 2. For example the output should be something like

25 1990
4  1991
7  1992

Comment: Welcome so SO & Julia! There are lots of ways you might think of doing this. I suggest having a look at the julia docs or a julia tutorial (both linked on the julia lang website) and having a think about how you might want to solve this programmatically. If you get stuck then you can ask a question here (and post some example code!). I would highly suggest getting familiar with the nuts and bolts before wading into parallel computing also.

Comment: Looks like there's a lot to unravel here. In fact, I am not sure I understand what the question is. You may want to get help in a friendly chatroom to help refine the question a bit. For that, you can stop by the [Julia Gitter](https://gitter.im/JuliaLang/julia) and we can help get you re-started.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy replies. I will do what is suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but as a beginner you may find it helpful to lean more upon higher level tools.  If you use the [`DataFrames` package](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/), then you can use it's higher level [split-apply-combine](https://dataframesjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/split_apply_combine.html) methodology.

I'll create a fake dataset using the column names `count` and `year` and random values.  If you're loading your data from CSV, note that you can create a DataFrame directly from it.  Otherwise, you can create a data frame from your existing matrix with `DataFrame(count=view(A, :, 1), year=view(A, :, 2))`.

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(count=rand(1:30, 5048574), year=rand(1900:2017, 5048574))
5048574×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row     │ count │ year │
├─────────┼───────┼──────┤
│ 1       │ 19    │ 1948 │
│ 2       │ 8     │ 1994 │
│ 3       │ 20    │ 1940 │
│ 4       │ 21    │ 2000 │
│ 5       │ 28    │ 1982 │
│ 6       │ 18    │ 1904 │
⋮
```

Now you can use the `groupby` operator to split your dataset into groups by year, and then pass that to the `sum` function:

```
julia> groupby(df, :year) |> sum
118×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ year │ count_sum │
├─────┼──────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 1900 │ 667412    │
│ 2   │ 1901 │ 663045    │
│ 3   │ 1902 │ 669364    │
│ 4   │ 1903 │ 665388    │
│ 5   │ 1904 │ 664468    │
│ 6   │ 1905 │ 664388    │
│ 7   │ 1906 │ 666246    │
⋮
```

You can see that it intelligently named your `count_sum` column.  Even on my old laptop, this took less than a second to complete.  There are certainly faster ways to do this, but I think that the ease of use here is well-worth it.

Comment: How to do it faster? I think that it is fair to say that most Julia users are primary users of R/Python/Matlab and come to Julia only when they need speed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this without DataFrames, a simple approach is to use a `Dict`ionary:

```
julia> s = Dict{Int,Int}()
Dict{Int64,Int64} with 0 entries

julia> for i = 1:size(A,1)
           v, y = A[i,1], A[i,2]
           if haskey(s, y)
               s[y] += v
           else
               s[y] = v
           end
       end

julia> s
Dict{Int64,Int64} with 3 entries:
  1990 => 25
  1992 => 7
  1991 => 4
```